# Why does file in AJAX call not receive request until iframe is done loading?

Tags: php, upload

I have an `index.php` that accepts multiple images via a file input element. When the user submits the form, the request is sent to a hidden iframe and the action file (`upload.php`) converts and moves the images to a new directory. I attached an `oninput` function via Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("new-upload").addEventListener("submit", function() {
    trackUpload();
});
function trackUpload() {
  var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("started");
    httpReq.open("GET", "progress.php");
    httpReq.send();
    console.log("sent");
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log("state change " + httpReq.readyState);
      if (httpReq.readyState === 4) {
        var httpRes = httpReq.responseText;
        console.log(httpRes);
        if (httpRes < 100) {
          setTimeout(trackUpload, 500);
          console.log("started");
        } else {
          //hide upload bar
        }
      }
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

When I hit the upload button, the files are uploaded and then my `upload.php` file is called and it converts the images. I confirmed that the images are all uploaded before the `upload.php` file is called by echoing `var_dump($_SESSION["upload_progress_images"])` which returned the finished upload array **only** when `session.upload_progress.cleanup` was set to `Off`. I console logged start, sent, and state changes for my `XMLHttpRequest` and it is being started and sent after a delay of 0.5 seconds like it's supposed to. However, it doesn't change to state 2 until the `upload.php` file is done converting and moving all the files. (Which is when the iframe finishes loading.) So why doesn't the `XMLHttpRequest` register that it received the request until then? Is my server limited to processing one file at a time or is it the browser?

EDIT

I tried to access another php page on my website while the php upload script was running and it didn't load until images were done loading. So that means that PHP can only do one thing at a time? If so, how would I accomplish my task above?

Comment: You can set the [intervals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) by yourself. Also note the warning `The web server's request buffering has to be disabled for this to work properly, else PHP may see the file upload only once fully uploaded. Servers such as Nginx are known to buffer larger requests.`

Comment: Note the request buffering. (Previous comment updated).